# Pick just images

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have 2 methods on my app to pick images from the phone. One accepts any kind of file so I use file_picker for it and the other one only accepts images.

How can I filter by type of file? Do I need to use a different package like this one? 
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: very useful to give negatives and no comments about them

Answer (score 0):

I can use just `FilePicker` package and do something like this

```
FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.CUSTOM, fileExtension: 'jpg');
```

Also `type: FileType.IMAGE` for any kind of image.

To take any file I can just remove the `fileExtension` and the `type`

Answer (score 0):

With [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) we can restrict selection for image only files by specifying the `type` parameter:

```dart
FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.IMAGE)
```

or for single file extension:

```dart
FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.CUSTOM, fileExtension: "JPG");
```